# Can I use the Launchpad translation service for my GitHub project?

Tags: application-development, launchpad, translation, github

For historical reasons, the project I co-author is on GitHub and we feel comfortable with its development processes.  Thus we don't particularly want to migrate the whole project to Launchpad and using bazaar.

Being good internet-citizens we want to provide our open-source application in as many languages as possible - we stumbled across whilst searching that Launchpad could provide such a service.

- https://help.launchpad.net/Translations

The above link gives lots of description on this service, but I need a concise - very brief - how to:

- get our translation file (`package.pot`) from GitHub into launchpad
- brief description how to kick off our project to be translated.
- pull back from launchpad any translation files (`.po`) that are generated by the wonderful translation team back into GitHub.

Does anybody have any practical experience do this that can help here?

Comment: Even I prefer Github, [now you can use git on Launchpad](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Git).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, Launchpad can be used to manage translations for a project on github.

You can test launchpad's features with [Launchpad Staging](https://staging.launchpad.net).

- Register your project on Launchpad. ([Instructions can be found here.](https://help.launchpad.net/Projects/Registering#Registration))
- Set up Launchpad to automatically import from Github. ([Launchpad help page](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Imports))
  Use https://launchpad.net/PROJECT/trunk/+setbranch to set up Launchpad to import automatically from Github.
- Set up translations. ([Launchpad help page](https://help.launchpad.net/Translations/YourProject/ImportingTemplates#Enabling_automatic_template_imports))
  Use https://translations.launchpad.net/PROJECT/trunk/+translations-settings to select  what is to be imported. Translation templates alone, or along with existing translation files, can be imported.

#### How things work?

- You push to github repo you set as source in step 2.
- Launchpad periodically checks, and updates the bzr repository.
- It then scans for any .pot or .po files, and adds them to the translations import queue.
- After a short while, the strings appear as 'Needs translation' and can be translated like anything else on launchpad.

#### What about pushing back to Github?

Sorry, but I don't think Launchpad is capable of that. However, LP can be set up to commit the translation files to a bzr branch on LP. It also allows you to manually download the translation files. These options can be found in the translation settings page.

Comment: LP have added support for git repository beside bzr. http://blog.launchpad.net/general/git-code-hosting-beta . But I'm not aware if translation is supported yet.